# Can you derive a parametric function which describes a crystallographic screw axis?

Tags: geometry, parametric, crystallography

A $2_{1}$ screw axis is defined as a 180-degree rotation followed by a translation of $\frac{1}{2}$ along a particular unit cell vector. In matrix form:

\begin{equation}
\begin{bmatrix}
    -1  &  0  &  0      \\
    0  &  1  &  0      \\
    0  &  0  &  -1
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
    x     \\
    y     \\
    z
\end{bmatrix} 
+
\begin{bmatrix}
    0     \\
    \tfrac{1}{2}     \\
    0
\end{bmatrix} 
= 
\begin{bmatrix}
    -x     \\
    \tfrac{1}{2} + y     \\
    -z
\end{bmatrix} \\
\end{equation}

This describes a $2_{1}$ screw axis about $y$. If we connect every point $(x, y, z)$, $(-x, \tfrac{1}{2}+y, -z)$, etc., we can make a spiral-like shape which looks like a screw. Is there some parametric function which describes this curve, and can we derive one for each type of screw axis?

[Here is an example](http://pd.chem.ucl.ac.uk/pdnn/symm1/screw3.htm) for the mirror-image $3_{1}$ and $3_{2}$ screw axes, which form enantiomorphic helices. But I cannot find a parametric equation formally relating them. How would that be derived?

Comment: I think you just need to combine the parametric equation of a circle ($x = a \cos(\omega(t+t_0)) $, $z = \sin(\omega(t+t_0)) $) with a linear function $y = y_0+v t$. You get a screw like curve, and now you only need to substitute the correct values of the parameters

Comment: Following @YuriyS, the only thing that you can get is a relationship between $\omega$ and $v$, by noting that in half a period of rotation you move half a unit cell in the $y$ direction.

Comment: There should be $a$ in front of sin as well, I made a typo. I agree with Andrei, not all these parameters are necessary

Comment: Thank you both. What would a concrete example look like? I understand that combining trig functions for $x$ and $z$ with a linear function for $y$ gives a generic screw-like curve for $2_{1}$ about $y$, but can we derive a specific formula given numerical data? For instance, say we wanted to work out a $2_{1}$ curve for the point $(1, 1, 1)$ and all its resultant transformations $(-1, 1.5, -1)$ etc.